# Illustrator: concat singles chars back to text to path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

In Illustrator, I sometimes get a problem with imported files saved by Inkscape, CorelDraw etc: text on a path got converted to single chars without being connected to the path. The path and the chars are still there.

I've put an example in the attachment (exported from CC to CS to be compatible to anyone).

I've found some scripts to concat the text to a straight line, but not back to the curved one. Of course, I could do it manually, but often there are hundrets of those fragments...

Anyone with an idea?

Best regards,
Lars-Daniel

Attachment:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=53427632882046848570

Answer (score 1):

- Select the text object (All of them meant to be on the path)
- `Edit > Cut`
- Select the **Type on a Path Tool**
- Click the path
- `Edit > Paste`
- Reinsert the spaces (because they will be lost in most cases)

Comment: Sorry, this is a work-around, but like I said: I don't want to do it manually, since I've some hundret fragments to merge. This will take like ages... Seems like I need to write a script, which reads the coordinates for each char and creates a new path under it?

Comment: err.. unless there's a built in feature, everything is a "work around". Did you even try? The copy/paste will merge all those "fragments" but you obviously did not even attempt my suggestion.

Comment: Please calm down, I didn't mark your answer at not useful. The way you described is like I do it all the time and I call it "manually". I've just written a script to get the x/y coordinated of each character. Now I can calculate spacing (or space) between them to reproduce a merged text. Now I need to figure out, how to put this text on a path by script. I'll post it when I'm finished.

Comment: I'm perfectly calm.

Comment: It's offtopic, but is it possible to put point text on a path without using Cut & Paste?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, which is why I suggested what I did.

Comment: http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140423034814/roblox-apocalypse-rising/images/2/2a/Anchorman-well-that-escalated-quickly.jpg